# Can't insert data into mutiple mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So i've just started learning the basics of php and mysql and I was trying to use it to hold message and conversation data from a messaging app I am currently programming. So today I was just trying to test adding a message to the message table and record it in the conversation table but each time it adds the message, skips the conversation, and moves on. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
function addMessage($user, $recipient, $message, $status) {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

    // attemp to connect to the server and database
    $db = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        exit("Error 01");
    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO Messages (Message) VALUES ('$message')";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);    
    $id = mysqli_insert_id($db);

    $query2 = "INSERT INTO Conversations (User, Recipient, MeId, Status, Received)
    VALUES ('$user', '$recipient', '$id', '$status', '0')";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query2);

    echo $result;
}
```

Comment: If it is skipping the `Conversations` query, there might be an error in your query. Check for errors -> `$result = mysqli_query($db, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($db));`

Comment: echo $query2 and copy the query and execute on mysql you will know the error in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply add `or die(mysqli_error($error));` at the end of your query

Like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query2) or die(mysqli_error($error));
```

You can see now error log.

Comment: Thanks that helped me find it. The error was I was putting true instead of 1 for the boolean column. I didn't realize I had to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP looks fine to me.

Is
    echo $result;
returning '0'?

If so, there's a problem with you SQL statement somewhere, maybe field is named wrong or it is not following the structure. Hard for me to know without seeing your DB. Turn on error reporting and see if it spits out any errors.

Comment: I'm programming my app on Android Studio and I print the response in the log 08-07 22:59:52.523  26490-26886/com.joebruckner.sparkmessenger D/Result﹕ [ 08-07 22:59:52.523 26490:26490 D/Task     ]